# Bootstrap pagination with php

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I followed the pagination tutorial http://www.developphp.com/view.php?tid=1349.
I try to use bootstrap framework (latest version) to style the pagination but I have a bug that i don't know how to fix:

[image]

How can i solve this?

here is my code,

```
$paginationCtrls = '';

if($last != 1){

    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a></li>  &nbsp; &nbsp; ';

        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0){
                $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>  &nbsp; ';
            }
        }
    }

    $paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';

    for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
        $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>  &nbsp; ';
        if($i >= $pagenum+4){
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($pagenum != $last) {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a></li>  ';
    }
}
```

and this is how i call it

```
echo '<ul class="pagination">'.$paginationCtrls.'</ul>';
```

Comment: Does that happen on all pages or only certain ones?

Comment: What is your actual HTML Output. Could it be that this line - `$paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';` which appears to output the 'current page' should be `$paginationCtrls .= '<li>'.$pagenum.'</li> &nbsp; ';`

Comment: Only happens with active pages

Comment: Thanks Rob, i tried that but it looks the same.